# WinSock: Sending and receiving messages (not in parallel)

Tags: c++, winsock2

Forgive me for the following, as my understanding of winsock is not quite yet complete (I have only started looking in to it over the past two days). For now, my question is brief and more of a "can I do this the way I want to do it?" ordeal. On to the inquiry itself:

A member of my lab has written a nice winsock server that communicates with a client to transmit instructions to various instruments connected via serial. That part is already written and thankfully I do not have to touch; it works universally for all serial devices. However, the existing clients are all written in MatLab, and I'm trying to rewrite them in C/C++.

I've managed to successfully connect to the server and establish a socket. I can receive the data it sends and display it on the client. Great!

The problem I'm having thus far - after all of the initial data (containing instructions) is sent to the client, I cannot do anything. It will display the received data as text, but does not break the simple do while loop I have and ask the user for an input to transmit.

I'm wondering if it possible to set up a receive-then-transmit loop between the server and the client, such that I can send a command and receive the response with one socket in the client until I am done with talking to the server?

I will post my code tomorrow morning once I'm back at my lab computer!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Also you may want to look up networking libraries such as [zeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/intro:read-the-manual)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you have to know when to stop receiving, so you can read the keyboard input instead, of course. If you're calling `recv` then you aren't calling `fgets` or `scanf` or `cin >>` or whatever you're using to read.